#  Does P≠NP over ℝ imply P≠NP ?

Tags: computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis

Does P≠NP over ℝ imply P≠NP ?

where ℝ is for Real number algorithms as described by Smale with a suitable formulation of P≠NP over ℝ.

Complexity Theory and Numerical Analysis, Steve Smale, 2000
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.4678&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Please give more information. Presumably you're talking about the Blum-Shub-Smale model of computation, and presumably by "R" you mean the real numbers.

Comment: Real number algorithms as described by Smale with a suitable formulation of P≠NP over R.

Comment: Some years ago I read the paper "Computing over the Reals, Where Turing Meets Newton" by Lenore Blum, in which this question and related questions ("transfer results") are addressed. Have you read this paper?

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for that paper. Question answered.

Comment: @Kevin Let me suggest changing your remark to an answer, so that the question can get closed.

Comment: Okay, it is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some years ago I read the paper "Computing over the Reals, Where Turing Meets Newton" by Lenore Blum, in which this question and related questions ("transfer results") are addressed: http://www.ams.org/notices/200409/fea-blum.pdf